# Set environment variable to parent directory if not already set

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I'm writing a bash script, and it needs to check if an environment variable exists, and set it to the parent directory of where the script is being run if the variable isn't already set.  If it is already set, it should do nothing.  What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two parts. First, the parent of the current working directory  is just `$PWD/..`. Second, you can assign a value to a variable if it isn't already set with

```
: ${MYVAR:=$PWD/..}
```

The first `:` is the do-nothing command, but its arguments are still evaluated. The parameter expansion operator `:=` has the side effect of setting `MYVAR` to the given value if it isn't already set.

Comment: Why didn't you use `${MYVAR:=${PWD%/*}}` ?

Comment: You probably could here. In general, though, removing the last `/` and anything following it does not necessarily remove the last path component. Consider a path that has a trailing `/`, e.g., `/home/me/`. Your suggestion would produce `/home/me`.

Comment: `: ${MYVAR:=$(dirname "$PWD")}`, as pointed out by @LjmDullaart, would be another option; I like to avoid running other processes where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

An environment variable is a globally available, in a program and it child programs. A shell variable is only available in the current shell. You asked to know whether the *environment* variable exists. Are you sure that is what you want? In that case you may want to do a

```
if set | grep ^variable_name= > /dev/null ; then
   #set the variable
fi
```

Note that this just checks if the variable exists. If you do it very early in your script, you are almost sure that the variable is indeed an environment variable. But do you really care if it is a variable specific to your local shell or an environment variable?

Second is, do you care if the variable exists? Or do you just want it to contain the value of the parent directory? Do you need the `set | grep` in the example above, or is it sufficient to test that `[ "$variable" != "" ]` ? , as in

```
if [ "$variable" = "" ] ; then
    # set the value to the parent-dir
fi
```

Third, the parent-dir is generally `dirname $PWD`. `$PWD/..` is also the parent-dir.

So, if you do not care whether it is is an environment variable or not, and if you just want it to contain an actual directory, the code would be something like:

```
if [ "$variable" = "" ] ; then
    variable=$(dirname "$PWD")
fi
```

(which is perhaps a bit more readable Chepner's answer)

Comment: Grepping the output of `set` isn't reliable. The value of another variable could contain the string you are checking for after a newline. Say you had `foo=$'bar\nbaz='`; your check would see `baz` as being a name when it is really just part of the value of `foo`.